# vue-bootstrap form-spinbutton with additional params

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I want to have a [b-form-spinbutton](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-spinbutton) formatter function with dependency of my data, so I want to pass additional argument to :formatter-fn. I am trying this code, but it doesnt work.

```
<b-form-spinbutton :formatter-fn='dividerFormatter(data.index, $event)'></b-form-spinbutton>
```

Documentation says:

> 'formatter-fn Function A reference to a method to format the displayed
> value. It is passed a **single** argument which is the current value'

Is it any way to pass additional parameter to this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write an inline function which takes the single argument and passes it to your formatter along with the additional parameters you need.

```html
<b-form-spinbutton :formatter-fn='(val) => dividerFormatter(data.index, val)'>
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      data: {
        index: 1,
        value: 0
      },
      days: ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday']
    }
  },
  methods: {
    dividerFormatter(index, value) {
      console.log(`Index: ${index} - Value ${value}`)
      return this.days[value]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.15.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.15.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <b-form-spinbutton v-model="data.value" :formatter-fn='(val) => dividerFormatter(data.index, val)' min="0" max="6">
  </b-form-spinbutton>
</div>
```